# In D3 chart, On Click is not working on circle as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In My D3 chart, OnClick is not working as expected.

Any suggestions ?
It seems because of focus line and focus circle it is creating the issue. 
Expected behaviour should be on click circle it should pop up alert.

PS: `.on("click"` works if i try to click on circle when focus line and circle is not present.

My Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h)

Code -

```
g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.startTime);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.magnitude);
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    if (d.startupRunningStatus === "OUT_OF_SYNC") {
      return 5;
    }
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    alert("on click" + d.magnitude);
  })
  .attr("class", "circle");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a stack issue. As you see in the screenshot, the `rect` overlays the circles. So you need to append the elements in order.

[image]

The quickets and easiest fix is to append `circle` after appending the `rect`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-brattain-vi5g4

Comment: This looks good, but once I append circle my tooltip is not showing at this point.

Comment: anything I can do so tooltip also comes and I am able to show click pointer on hover and user will able to click.

Comment: If you want to show tooltip when you hover  on circle, then you must attach `.on('mouseover')` to the circle. @JavascriptCoder